# Surface area of $z=4-x^2-y^2$ over a square region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Find the surface area of the paraboloid $z=4-x^2-y^2$ over the square region $-2\le x\le 2 $ and $-2\le y\le 2$.

I can parametrize this surface with $x=u,\ y=v,\text{and}  \>z=4-u^2-v^2$,
where $-2\le u\le 2$ and $-2\le v\le 2$. Then I can parametrize the surface with a vector function as follows:
$$\mathbf r(u,v)=\langle u, v ,4-u^2-v^2\rangle $$
Then
$\mathbf r_u(u,v)=\langle 1,0,-2u\rangle,\>
\mathbf r_v(u,v)=\langle 0,1,-2v\rangle$ and
$$\mathbf r_u\times\mathbf r_v=\left|\matrix{\mathbf i&\mathbf j&\mathbf k\cr 1 & 0 & -2u\cr 0 & 1 & -2v}\right|=\langle 2u,2v,1\rangle$$
so $\|\mathbf r_u\times\mathbf r_v\|=\sqrt{4u^2+4v^2+1}$.
The surface area is then defined by
$$A=\int\int_D\|\mathbf r_u\times \mathbf r_v\|\,dA=\int_{-2}^2\int_{-2}^2\sqrt{4u^2+4v^2+1}\,dv\,du$$
But now, how do I perform this integral? Here's an image of this surface.

[image]
**Update**

Due to symmetry, we can calculate the surface area over the region $R=\{(u,v):\ 0\le u\le 2\text{ and }0\le v\le 2\}$, then multiply the result by 4. That is, the surface area is

$$A=4\int_{0}^2\int_{0}^2\sqrt{4u^2+4v^2+1}\,dv\,du$$

Now, it was suggested that I try polar coordinates. Here's an image of the region $R=\{(u,v):\ 0\le u\le 2\text{ and }0\le v\le 2\}$.

[image]

Note that the angle of the dashed segment from $(0,0)$ to $(2,2)$ has an angle of $\pi/4$ with the $u$-axis. Also, note that

\begin{align*}
\cos\theta&=\frac2r\\
r\cos\theta&=2\\
r&=\frac{2}{\cos\theta}\\
r&=2\sec\theta
\end{align*}

Again, because of the symmetry of our image, we can determine the surface area over the region $\{(r,\theta):\ 0\le \theta\le \pi/4\text{ and } 0\le r\le 2\sec\theta\}$ and multiply the result by 8. Thus, using
$$ u=r\cos\theta\qquad\text{and}\qquad v=r\sin\theta$$
the surface area is

\begin{align*}
A&=8\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{2\sec\theta}\sqrt{4r^2\cos^2\theta+4r^2\sin^2\theta+1}\ r\,dr\,d\theta\\
A&=8\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{2\sec\theta}\sqrt{4r^2+1}\ r\,dr\,d\theta\\
\end{align*}

Then I was able to integrate and manipulate a bit:
\begin{align*}
A&=8\int_0^{\pi/4}\left[\frac1{12}(4r^2+1)^{3/2}\right]_0^{2\sec\theta}\,d\theta\\
A&=\frac23\int_0^{\pi/4}\left[(16\sec^2\theta+1)^{3/2}-1\right]\,d\theta\\
A&=\frac23\int_0^{\pi/4}(16\sec^2\theta+1)^{3/2}\,d\theta-\frac23\int_0^{\pi/4}d\theta\\
A&=\frac23\int_0^{\pi/4}(16\sec^2\theta+1)^{3/2}\,d\theta-\frac{\pi}{6}
\end{align*}

But now I am unable to calculate this current integral.

Thanks.

**Update**

Click the link below to see the work I had to do to understand Quanto's nice suggestion.

[Surface Area Solution](https://stmartin0-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/personal/darnold_stmartin_edu/Ea4GBhvtYaxGlzhPtRrcypsB1ndbNPoIzFnT5nRze_yBag?e=rZyK69)

Comment: Have you considered converting this integral into polar coordinates?

Comment: @MatthewPilling I've updated my polar coordinate attempt, but still stuck.

Comment: I do not know, but you might come up with another idea on how to solve $$-\int_{\lambda\prime} \frac{u^4du}{(u^2 - 16)\sqrt{17-u^2}}$$ which corresponds to your terminal integral, wherein it was put $u^2 = 16 + \cos^2 \theta$;should you make another substitution like $u^2 - 16 = 1/t$ you then get $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{\lambda \prime \prime} \sqrt{\frac{16t+1}{t-1}}\cdot\frac{16+t}{t^2}dt$$

Comment: And it seems though we know how to solve integrals like $$\int_{\lambda \prime \prime} \sqrt{\frac{16t+1}{t-1}}\frac{16t+1}{t^2}dt$$ in the comment above, it has a huge antiderivative; whereas the first one does not; I feel that we might apply the method of unknown coefficients (reduce the integral to another) to this integral. To solve the other one, which is equivalent to the previous, we may make another substitution to get rid of the root; but will you?

Comment: Putting $s = \sqrt{\frac{16t+1}{t-1}}$ brings you to the integral $$-17 \int_{\lambda \prime \prime \prime} \frac{16s^6-239s^4-272s^2}{(s^2+1)^2(s^2 - 16)^2}ds  $$, which the integral of rational function. The next step is to break this into several integrals and complete integration... But that seems not easy. Note the degree of the numerator is 6, and that of the denominator is 8, so we have the proper fraction, which is irreducible. Now we must apply the method of unknown coefficients and decompose the whole fraction into sum of little ones.

Comment: Notice that: $$\frac{16s^6 - 239s^4 - 272s^2}{(s^2+1)^2(s^2-16)^2} = \frac{-\frac{205}{32}s - \frac{717}{32}}{(s-4)^2}+\frac{\frac{205}{32}s + \frac{717}{32}}{(s+4)^2} + \frac{-\frac{272}{256}s^2}{(s^2+1)^2}$$ The first two things are easily integrated; the last one is by parts. Why? Becase you do know about $$\int \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^n}dx$$. So, do it and remember about replacement - you do definite integral, meaning that you do not have to get back to those; hence, you must define new limits of integration and complete this guy ^) And I took your integral without 2/3 and that term $-\pi/6$.

Comment: You could bound the square region between two circles, of diameter=length of the square's side and length of the square's diagonal and easily apply polar coordinates for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\sinh t= {\frac{4}{\sqrt{17}}}\tan\theta$ to evaluate

\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^{\pi/4}(16\sec^2\theta+1)^{3/2}\,d\theta\\
&=\frac{17^2}4\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}\frac{4}{\sqrt{17}}}
\frac{\cosh^4 t}{1+\frac{17}{16}\sinh^2t }dt
=34\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}\frac{4}{\sqrt{17}}}
\frac{(1+\cosh 2t)^2}{\frac{15}{17}+\cosh2t}dt\\
 &=\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}\frac{4}{\sqrt{17}}}
\left(34 \cosh2t + 38 + \frac{8}{{15}+17\cosh2t}\right)dt\\
&= 8\sqrt{33} + 38 \sinh^{-1}\frac{4}{\sqrt{17}}+\ 4\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}\frac{4}{\sqrt{17}}}\frac{d(\tanh t)}{16+\tanh^2t}\\
 &= 8\sqrt{33} + 38 \sinh^{-1}\frac{4}{\sqrt{17}}+\cot^{-1}\sqrt{33}
\end{align}

Thus, the surface area is
$$A=\frac23I-\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac23\left( 
 8\sqrt{33} + 38 \sinh^{-1}\frac{4}{\sqrt{17}}+\cot^{-1}\sqrt{33} -\frac\pi4\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you, though I am not the one who posted the question but the one who commented on it, trying to help the asker. For some reason, I did not think about the hyperbolic trigonometric functions... I have no clue if my solution is good and leads to the same answer - but those calculations that I made are so huge, so long that I would not verify my answer; hopefully, the polynomial were beautiful and the fraction was easily decomposed. Maybe I did the integral right but in a very very long way :) Have a great day, sir and be happy during Christmas!

Comment: @Quanto I've added a link to the file of my work that I had to do to understand your nice suggestion. The link is up above at the end of my question.

Comment: @David - your diligence is rather impressive.